# Can not create App-pool SpecificUser Identity inside Windows Containers

Tags: iis, application-pool, windows-server, docker-container

I am trying out Windows Containers based on `microsoft/dotnet35` image on Windows Server 2016 TP5 for my Web App. I need to set up App-pool Identity to specific user, but I am getting an error. when running below command inside a Windows Container.

```
C:\>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:spark /processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /processModel.username:Domain\username /processModel.password:test
```

> APPPOOL object "spark" changed ERROR ( hresult:80090016,
>   message:Failed to commit configuration changes. Keyset does not exist 
>   )

I can not connect to my database without setting this up as I am using Windows Authentication.

Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around I finally found the issue. The error was gone after I ran below command,

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\iissetup.exe /install SharedLibraries
```

Comment: That is just...odd. It worked, but i have to run this command after every Azure deployment now.

Comment: I get Failed = 0x80070005 when I run this command in an admin command prompt. :(